# VS Running SQL query against local database

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I am trying to execute SQL query on a local databse that I created inside visual studio (service based database option). However when I click "Execute" I get the "Connect to Server" message and it asks for server name.

I have no idea what to enter, I tried SQLEXPRESS, my computer name, localhost. none of these work!! Please help this is so frustrating to do a basic thing...

Comment: What about the server instance? SQL Servers are now come with an option to install multiple instances. Your localhost may have this configuration. Open SSIS and check what you have

Comment: how do I open SSIS? I am not sure what it is sorry.

Comment: I think you need to change "Data Source" to Microsoft SQL Server Database file. When you do so, you will need to navigate to your SQLEXPRESS file you have created

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured  it out. Once I restarted VS, a new server appeared under the servers tab. It's actually called "(localdb)\Projects"

Once I specified that into server name, everything connected fine.